# go mod subdirectories structure

Tags: go, go-modules

I'm using the following struct on my project, but it feels hacky

```
App
├── go.mod
├── app.go
└── src
    └── foo
    |    └── foo.go
    └── bar
        └── bar.go
```

Is there a way to organize it like that?

```
App
├── go.mod
└── src
    ├── app.go
    └── foo
    |    └── foo.go
    └── bar
        └── bar.go
```

Comment: Why do you have a `src` directory at all?

Comment: I like to keep my code separated from my other configs

Comment: That's not how Go projects are organized, and it means that `src` will be in all your import paths.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could just move the `app.go` file into the src directory.

However, it's generally ill-advised to have an src folder in a Go project. I recommend you take a look [here](https://github.com/golang-standards/project-layout) for recommendations re: project structure.

Answer (score 0):

I like the following structure

```
App
├── makefile
├── go.mod
├── httpd <- Entrypoint is here - CLI or Http Server
|   └── main.go
└── platform <- Project specific dependencies that are not shared between projects
```

e.g

```
App
├── makefile
├── go.mod
├── httpd
|   └── handlers
|   |    └── hello-world_get.go
|   |    └── hello-world_get_test.go
|   └── main.go
└── platform
    └── user
        └── user.go
        └── user_test.go
```

I describe it here on YouTube
https://youtu.be/zeme_TmXyBk